# ExcelPackage throws "File contains corrupted data" error

Tags: moss, excelpackage

I am trying to upload a excel file onto a moss 2007 site. In the event handler I try to read the file using ExcelPackage. 
My code is as below...

```
MemoryStream fileContent = new MemoryStream();
   fileContent.Write(properties.ListItem.File.OpenBinary(), 0, Convert.ToInt32(properties.ListItem.File.TotalLength));
   using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(fileContent))
   {
       ExcelWorksheet worksheetWR = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
       .....
   }
```

But I am always receiving the **File contains corrupted data** 
error at the using stmt. I have been trying to find a solution for this for quite sometime but so far no break through.
Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Any ideas for solving this? I would really be grateful for any ideas :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used *MS Office Interop Excel* to read the same excel without any errors.